# Multiplication table Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, multiplication

I am trying to make a multiplication table 10x10 by using nested for loops that will open in excel. So far, I have this to open excel:

```
$excel = New-Object -COMObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$excel.Workbooks.Add()
```

And this to display the table:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j -lt 10; $j++) {
        $total = $i * $j;
        Write-output $total 
    }
}
```

But the table does not display in 10x10 format table but one under the other. Can someone help me put this together or give me some hints how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

- Your 2 `for` loops should have the same exit condition (`-le 10)`.
- Each time you use `Write-Output` it writes a new line to the console.
- You only have the first lines needed for Excel, you need a few more
  :).

If you wanted to output the table to the console you could have done it this way :

```
#for each row
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
    #declare an array to hold the row values
    $row = @()
    #for each column
    for ($j = 1; $j -le 10; $j++)  {
        #add value to array
        $row += $i * $j
    }
    #output the array, joining cells with tabs (`t)
    $row -join "`t"
}
```

Output :

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Now if you want to output this to Excel, here's how you can do :

```
#create Excel Application object
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

#make Excel window visible
$excel.Visible = $true

#create a new workbook
$book = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

#select the first sheet
$sheet = $book.Worksheets.Item(1)

#name it as you like
$sheet.Name = "Multiply"

#build the header row (bold)
for ($j = 1; $j -le 10; $j++)  {
    $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $j + 1).Value2 = $j
    $sheet.Cells.Item(1, $j + 1).Font.Bold = $true
}

#build the other rows
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10; $i++) {

    #"header" cell (bold)
    $sheet.Cells.Item($i + 1, 1).Value2 = $i
    $sheet.Cells.Item($i + 1, 1).Font.Bold = $true

    #other cells
    for ($j = 1; $j -le 10; $j++)  {
        $sheet.Cells.Item($i + 1, $j + 1).Value2 = $i * $j
    }
}
```

Try this and tell me if you need adjustments. I'll comment the code so you can understand better.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The only little issue i have is that the header row is not showing all the numbers. There is only number 1 in cell B1 in header row. The rest is empty from C1-K1. I tried to correct this but I did come up as it supposed to. Thanks again!

Comment: Well it's strange, I cannot reproduce this. If you are pleased with the answer nonetheless, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the mark under the votes

Comment: I made a little mistake with curly braces. I solve my problem. Thank You again!